# Remove duplicate products with same sku in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have used wp all import http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-xml-csv-product-import/ to import products from a XML file, but it has created duplicate products with same SKU. how can i delete duplicates and leave the most recent one? Maybe a database query? or is there a woocommerce/wordpress option I am missing?

Thank you

Comment: Duplicate for each products or for some? If it created duplicate for each product you can delete all products and re-import them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Allaerd`'s delete produt by SKU.

It can be found here

[Delete Produtcs by SKU](https://allaerd.org/shop/delete-products-imported/)

*Plugin Description*

Put’s products on status trash that are not in the last CSV. It uses the SKU’s to do this. At the beginning of the import, all products are marked. For products that are imported / merged the mark is removed. The products that still have the mark after all rows are processed, will be pur on status trash.

Hope it works. Good Luck!