# How to delete dupliacte Woocommerce Products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a wordpress installation that imported products in from a large database of products. The installation is supposed to have 4436 products in it, but for some reason when I imported, it made duplicates of almost all of the products.

What can I do to remove the duplicates? They all have names and skus.

http://update.pinkdynamite.co.uk/

Comment: Hi, there is same question asked here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939334/remove-duplicate-products-with-same-sku-in-woocommerce, maybe it could help

Comment: To get the list of duplicate product you can use this SQL query. `SELECT post_id, meta_value
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key = '_sku'
AND meta_value != ''
GROUP BY meta_value HAVING COUNT(meta_value) > 1`.

Answer (score 0):

If the imported products is duplicated, you should find the root cause. For a normal import, it should not be duplicated.

My suggestion is remove all products and import again.

To delete all products at one time, you can use WP-CLI.

```
wp post delete $(wp post list --post_type='product' --format=ids)
```

https://wp-cli.org/commands/post/delete/